# Given two points and a an angle, find the radius of the circle that intersects both points

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, circles

Given the points **a** and **b** and the angle **alpha** (which is the angle between the vector from **a** to **b** and the circle tangent vector at **a**), how do I find the radius **r** of the circle that intersects **a** and **b**?

[image: diagram]

Comment: Do you know the distance between points A and B? If so then one way is to use [Al Kashi's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) on the isosceles triangle ABC

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Yes,@Stef, I know the distance. I know the location of both a and b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that you know the distance $AB$. Let's call $d$ this distance.

We also know all the angles in triangle ABC:
\begin{align*}
\hat{A} & = \frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha \\
\hat{B} & = \hat{A} = \frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha \\
\hat{C} & = \pi - \hat{A} - \hat{B} = \pi - 2 \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha \right) = 2 \alpha \\
\end{align*}

Then by application of [Al Kashi's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) to triangle ABC:
\begin{align*}
AB^2 & = AC^2 + BC^2 - \cos(\hat{C}) \\
d^2 & = 2 r^2 - \cos(\alpha) \\
r^2 & = \frac 1 2 \left( d^2 + \cos(2 \alpha) \right) \\ 
\end{align*}